# Why my nightwatch test returns "not visible"?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

im trying to use Nightwatch JS for a simple test and it not working.

Here is my test code:

```
module.exports = {
'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
  client
   .url('http://www.google.com')
   .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
   .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
   .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
   .click('button[name=btnG]')
   .pause(1000)
   .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
   .end();
 }
};
```

It returns:

```
Timed out while waiting for element <body> to be visible for 1000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not visible"
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: `.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)` - 1000 ms is 1s, the page will not load in such a short time. I would use 10 second, maybe even 60 seconds.Secondly <body> tag is not visible on the page  - it is not rendered on the page like button or link. You cannot check for it's visibility but only for it's presence, use another method `waitForElementPresent`

Comment: @krokodilko you could be right about seconds, but it is ok to check body tag visibility. Even it is not really visible as rendered window object.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout from 1000 to 3000 for body element to be visible and it should work.

```
.waitForElementVisible('body', 3000)
```

Also to be sure that it doesn't time out while finding the element 'button[name=btnG]', increase the time out to 3000 here as well.

```
.waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 3000)
```